# Get Child Divs inside Parent Divs according to data-'key' Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

Could you help me out with putting child divs inside parent divs (revursevly)
I have this code in html.

I need to put child .wrapper divs inside parent ones according to data retrieved from data-id and data-parent. Thanks in advance!

```
@model IEnumerable<Tree_List.Models.H_Table>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@*<script src="~/Scripts/ListControlScript.js"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id="wrapper" class="something" data-id="@item.PARENT_ID" data-parent="@item.PARENT_ID">
        <ul>
            <input type="button" class="toggler" onclick="ShowMsg()">
            <li class="roots" >
                @item.NAME
                <input class="add_btn" type="button" value="Add" />
                <input class="edit_btn" type="button" value="Edit" />
                <input class="delete_btn" type="button" value="Delete" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Data retrieved from where ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @Krishna To put div inside div as in "parent-child relation" using data from data-id and data-parent that come from a database through Model as a connection.

Comment: So if parent Id is null then it's a parent, if it has a parent id it's child right ?

Comment: @Krishna Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @model IEnumerable<Tree_List.Models.H_Table>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/ListControlScript.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <div>
    @helper PopulateDivs(IEnumerable<Tree_List.Models.H_Table> foos)
     {

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <div id="wrapper" class="something" data-id="@item.PARENT_ID" data-parent="@item.PARENT_ID">
          //I don't know the real structure you are looking for but this will work with recursion
             @if(Model.Any(m=> m.Parent_ID == item.ID))
               {
                  @PopulateDivs(Model.Where(m=> m.Parent_ID == item.ID))
               }
             <ul>
                <input type="button" class="toggler" onclick="ShowMsg()">
                <li class="roots" >
                    @item.NAME
                    <input class="add_btn" type="button" value="Add" />
                    <input class="edit_btn" type="button" value="Edit" />
                    <input class="delete_btn" type="button" value="Delete" />
                </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
        }

      }

     </div>

    <script>
        $(function () {

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work though if the view expands (these childs have their childs)

Comment: Maybe it is possible in javascript - something like a recursion

Comment: You mean to say you have multi-level hierarchy ?

Comment: Yes, multi-level

Comment: it says "the type of namespace Foo cannot be found"

Comment: Check now, you need to change it to fit your needs

Comment: So, I just add a recursion and that's it?

Comment: Yes, recursion in razor

Comment: So, I add the recursion in the place of the comment? Sorry, I may appear dumb but the brain already refuses to work =)

Comment: Yes depending on your structure you need to create child divs wherever required